# How can base64 encoded replies be requested for `getProgramAccounts`

Tags: getprogramaccounts

I am currently using
`getProgramAccounts` but receiving following error.

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "error":{
      "code":-32600,
      "message":"Encoded binary (base 58) data should be less than 128 bytes, please use Base64 encoding."
   },
   "id":1
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the body of your RPC call?

Comment: Yes. Please edit your answer to share that and the relevant code snippet where you call `getProgramAccounts` + compute the arguments you feed it, as well. It looks like you are providing a pubkey or something in the wrong format maybe, but nothing can be identified with what you posted.

Answer (score 3):

The `getProgramAccounts` method is limited to Account data of less than 129 bytes when using `base58` encoding. You can specify `base64` in the encoding field of the options parameter to avoid this limit.

See the API for the method here: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts